# Execute code in background after render page in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a script with twilio:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

def wa(testo):
    client = Client()
    # this is the Twilio sandbox testing number
    from_whatsapp_number='whatsapp:+14155238886'
    to_whatsapp_number='whatsapp:+39xxxxxxxxxx'
    ts = 'Anomalia Rapportino ' + str(testo)
    client.messages.create(body=ts,
                           from_=from_whatsapp_number,
                           to=to_whatsapp_number)
```

I imported this script in view and I have this def:

```
def grazieeprint(request, pk):
    intermedio = get_object_or_404(IntermProd, pk=pk)
    datilavoro = WhoWork.objects.get(pk=intermedio.work_id)
    try:
        return render(request, 'FBIsystem/thanksandprint.html', {'pkpreso': pk})

    finally:
        try:
            appo = datilavoro.pezziorastima * 2
            if datilavoro.pezziora >= appo:
                testo = datilavoro.pk
                subprocess.Popen([wa(testo)], shell=True)
        except:
            pass
```

I need to run 'wa(testo)' after django load the page because all the process of sending message take approx 15/20 sec.

I try whit 'try and finally' and whit 'subbrocess.Popen' but it send always the message before render the page.

Please help

TY

EDIT:

I try:

```
    finally:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
            appo = datilavoro.pezziorastima * 2
            if datilavoro.pezziora >= appo:
                testo = datilavoro.pk
                subprocess.Popen([wa(testo)], shell=True)
```

it load page fast, but not send

EDIT 2:

Trying use Celery, now script is:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
from celery import shared_task,current_task

@shared_task
def wa(testo):
    print 'test'
    client = Client()
    # this is the Twilio sandbox testing number
    from_whatsapp_number='whatsapp:+14155238886'
    to_whatsapp_number='whatsapp:+39xxxxxxxxx'
    ts = 'Anomalia Rapportino ' + str(testo)
    client.messages.create(body=ts,
                           from_=from_whatsapp_number,
                           to=to_whatsapp_number)
```

but not work in parallel...
what is the right way?

Comment: Maybe not a optimal solution, but you can use `time.sleep(<seconds>)` to wait till running `wa(testo)`

Comment: Send the task to a background process. Search for [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

Comment: and without Celery? there is a solution with subprocess?

Comment: tryed to use Celery but not work async

Comment: you can try https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: i tryed but it need to run 'python manage.py process_tasks' for complete tasks...